# If Field3 is contained in Field1 then Modify Field1 (Awk)

Tags: awk

I am trying to implement this logic with Awk:

If $3 is in $1 then replace the “$3 part of $1 and 1 blank space” with “” (blanks).
Print this new line and all other lines.

e.g. In my output (below) “Paris” in field $3 is found in field $1.  So “Paris “ is replaced by “” in field $1.

INPUT FILE

```
field1|field2|field3
abc Paris Match|xxxx|Paris
aaaaa|yyyyy|London
```

OUTPUT NEEDED

```
field1|field2|field3
abc Match|xxxx|Paris
aaaaa|yyyyy|London
```

CODE TRIED (Not working)

```
awk ' BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|"}
{
   { if ( $1 ~ /$3/ )  { print $0 }  }
} '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} s=index($1,$3){$1=substr($1,1,s-1) substr($1,s+length($3)); gsub(/ +/," ",$1)} 1' file
field1|field2|field3
abc Match|xxxx|Paris
aaaaa|yyyyy|London
```

The above assumes you don't care if any existing sequences of multiple blanks in $1 are also compressed to single blanks.

Answer (score 0):

here is one approach

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} 
             {sub($3,"",$1)}1' file

field1|field2|field3
abc  Match|xxxx|Paris
aaaaa|yyyyy|London
```

note that there are two spaces between remaining words.